# jQuery When Div is clicked go to url in a new tab, Except when Child item is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a Div structure and when the div is clicked I want a link to open in a new tab. But there is a child item inside the div which has a function of copying the code. When this child item is clicked, it should not open the link in new tab.

This is my HTML structure:

```js
$(".nuget").on('click', ':not(.copy-nuget-section)', function (e) {
     window.open('http://google.pl', '_blank')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item nuget">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img class="img-responsive add-shadow" alt="" src="/img/nuget-logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h3>Install with <span>NuGet</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="copy-nuget-section" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Click to copy">
      <div class="copy-nuget-row">
        <pre class="install-script">Install-Package</pre>
        <div class="copy-button">
          <button class="btn btn-default copy-nuget-script" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Copied." aria-label="Copy the Package Manager command" data-original-title="" title="">
            <span class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Copy"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nuget-link">nuget.org/packages/</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a builtin HTML/CSS/Javascript fiddle - please use it rather than external ones to make it easier for answerers (<> button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the `target` is `.copy-nuget-section` or any of it's children using `closest()`

```js
$(".nuget").on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.copy-nuget-section').length) {
    window.open('http://google.pl', '_blank')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item nuget">
  <div class="product-image">
    <img class="img-responsive add-shadow" alt="" src="/img/nuget-logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="product-info">
    <h3>Install with <span>NuGet</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="copy-nuget-section" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Click to copy">
    <div class="copy-nuget-row">
      <pre class="install-script">Install-Package</pre>
      <div class="copy-button">
        <button class="btn btn-default copy-nuget-script" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Copied." aria-label="Copy the Package Manager command" data-original-title="" title="">
            <span class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Copy"></span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nuget-link">nuget.org/packages/</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of event bubbling to stop the propagation of click event from child to parent like this.

```
$(".copy-nuget-section").on('click', function (e) {
   // code for the copy functionality that you want to implement
   e.stopPropagation()
});

$(".nuget").on('click', function (e) {
   window.open('http://google.pl', '_blank')
});
```